# Projections in von Neumann algebra tensor product

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, oa.operator-algebras, operator-theory, von-neumann-algebras

Let $\mathcal M\subseteq B(\mathcal H)$ be a von Neumann algebra with normal faithful semifinite trace $\tau.$ Consider the von Neumann algebra $\mathcal N:=L_\infty([0,1])\overline{\otimes}\mathcal M$ to be the von Neumann algebra tensor product. My question is projections and positive elements of the algebraic tensor product $L_\infty([0,1]){\otimes}\mathcal M$ are dense in the set of projections and positive elements of $\mathcal N$ in the $w^*$ topology or not? Suppose $e\in\mathcal N$ be a projection (or positive element) then does there exist an increasing sequence of projections (positive elements) in $L_\infty([0,1]){\otimes}\mathcal M$ converging to $e.$ Also can a projection of $\mathcal N$ be regarded as an $\mathcal M$ valued measurable operator and vise versa?

Comment: Can't you just say, that for vN algebras $A$ and $B$, as linear combinations of projections in $B$ are dense, the linear span of projections of the form $p\otimes q$ are dense in $p\otimes B$, then for any $b\in B$, linear combinations of elements the form $p\otimes b$ are dense in $A\otimes B$ and hence in the completion?